# League of Legends error on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

I installed LoL on ubuntu 13.10 and it was working properly. Now i updated to 14.04 and after update when i want to start the game it exits with error message. Reinstall could solve my problem? or what should i do with it? I can post the error details if needed.

Comment: You really need to post the error details and the logfile for anyone here to be able to help.

Comment: Are you using play on linux? If so, which wine version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done a comprehensive guide on "How to play League of Legends on Ubuntu 14.04". It covers everything: optimus notebooks, maestro disconnection error, user store error, in game shop big items etc... now League of Legends is 100% working here! If it helps you too, please, up vote my guide (:

[How to install League of Legends in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/459888/league-of-legends-on-14-04-shop-and-in-game-item-shop-not-working/461256#461256)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Play on Linux then there is a known problem with an old version of libxcb packaged with PoL.

The bugfix is to delete libxcb from PoL and eventually replace it with a new one.

For details see those posts on the official PoL forum.

- [League of Legends crashes after update to ubuntu 14.04](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/topic-11799-League_of_Legends_crashes_after_update_to_ubuntu_1404.html)
- [Bug # 3814 on Play on Linux](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/issue-3814.html)