# How to install League of Legends in Ubuntu

Tags: games, playonlinux

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and PlayOnLinux 4.2.2. I managed to get League of Legends almost running perfectly, there are only two problems. The first is that the shop to buy things with IP/RP is just a black screen. Here is a screenshot:

[image: League of Legends - Empty shop]

The second problem is that in the game, during the match, some menus are messed up, as if they were in a different resolution from the game's current resolution. For example, the item shop opens a normal window, but this window's contents are all over the screen. Here is a screenshoot:

[image: League of Legends - Broken in-game shop]

All the rest is working fine, I even get high FPS. I installed LoL via PlayOnLinux and then I applied TuxLoL patch. I have an Optimus Notebook, Dell Inspiron 14R 5421, it has an Intel integrated video card and Nvidia GeForce 730M dedicated card, which are properly handled by Bumblebee.

How do I fix these two problems? Could somebody help me, please?

Comment: What version of mono package do you have installed? I've tried with mono-runtime (3.2.8) and I get that http://pastebin.com/kbwqWmPp Installing mono-devel (3.2.8) packages I get that http://pastebin.com/ZbA8rQ21 Thanks!

Comment: Your solution does not seem to fix all the problems as you don't mention anymore the problem of the outgame shop. I don't know if you still have an issue but after following your tuto I remain with a black screen for 5 seconds and then the game shut down just after opening RP/IP shop.

Comment: @ElNikopol, I mentioned in the end of my answer that user store is working and I even posted 3 print screens showing it's working.

Comment: See also: https://github.com/TheUnnamedDude/pol_league_of_legends

Comment: I know this question is pretty  old but does LoL still work on linux with the recent changes to riot's client?  I haven't dug into this but I am very interested in switching completely to linux and am contemplating doing so but might not.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> **Answer updated**: as of September 2015, only steps 1, 2 and 3 are required for a 100% working League of Legends on Ubuntu 14.04

I've finally solved all problems and League of Legends is working 100%. Here is a comprehensive tutorial on **HOW TO PLAY LEAGUE OF LEGENDS ON UBUNTU 14.04**.

1. **Install your video card driver** (in my case, I have a NVIDIA GeForce 730M):

   Open *Unity Settings --> Software & Updates --> Additional Drivers* and click on the proprietary driver option. Here is a screenshot:

   [image: Software and Updates Dialog]
2. **Install PlayOnLinux:**

   ```
   sudo apt-get install playonlinux
   ```
3. **Install League of Legends through PlayOnLinux**

   - Open Play On Linux
   - Click "Install"
   - Type "league of legends"
   - Select the game and click "Install" buttom.

   Here is a printscreen:

   [image: PoL install menu]

   Just click *Next >> Next* >> Next* >> Finish*. Make sure you don't change anything, install in the default directory (don't change anything in the installer) and unmark "Launch League of Legends" when the installation is over.
4. **Install TuxLoL** (not needed any more, it's here just for reference)

   - Download it from here: https://bitbucket.org/Xargoth/tuxlol/wiki/Home
   - Unzip anywhere you want
   - Enter the folder you just unzipped (where there is the tuxlol.exe file) and execute it:

     ```
     $ mono tuxlol.exe patch --dir "LEAGUE_OF_LEGENDS_DIR"
     ```

     Obviously, replace `LEAGUE_OF_LEGENDS_DIR` with your League of Legends directory. In my case, it's installed here:

     ```
     ~/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/LeagueOfLegends/drive_c/Riot Games/League of Legends/
     ```

     *PS: You'll have to reapply this patch everytime a new LoL update is released.*
5. **Prevent in game store big items** (not needed any more, it's here just for reference)

   - Navigate to /home/[username]/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/[virtualdrivename]/drive_c/Riot Games/League of Legends/RADS/solutions/lol_game_client_sln/releases/[0.0.0.XXX]/deploy/DATA/menu/hud
   - Open the file corresponding to the resolution you play with. For example hud1680x1050.ini
   - Add these lines and save:

     ```
     [TipTracker]
     XPos=-20000
     YPos=-20000
     ```

   If you don't do this, in game store icons will be too big, here is a print screen:

   [image: mismatched sizes game view]

   After adding these lines, your in game store will be just fine:

   [image: correct game view]

PS: some people reported they had to install Internet Explorer using PlayOnLinux for the store to work. But for me, it worked just fine.

7. **Play the game!**

   To play the game, just open PlayOnLinux, select League of Legends and click "Run". Remember, if you have an Optimus Notebook, you must open PlayOnLinux as mentioned in section 5 every time. Here are some screen-shots of the game running:

   - https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdvH5.jpg
   - https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGbDn.jpg
   - https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNRn9.jpg
   - https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLdtw.jpg

As you can see, League of Legends is working 100% on Ubuntu 14.04: user store, in game item shop, Maestro connection and all the maps. Just make sure you follow these instructions to the risk. If I helped you, please upvote.

Comment: I canceled @Braiam's changes, so the images can be clearer and you all can see better what were the errors and the instructions those images were showing. I accepted all the other editions, thanks!

Comment: You should cite your sources (e.g. http://www.playonlinux.com/en/topic-11029.html).

Comment: @BenC I used about 10 different sources to put all these information together, the one you posted is only one of them. I didn't put links to all of them because some are not totally correct. In my compilation I filtered only the information that  worked on Ubuntu 14.04 to produce a 100% working League of Legends.

Comment: some details may be missing for people trying to debug their install. There's often long talks with tips on how to debug some issues. This can also be quite useful ;-)

Comment: There is also a great tutorial on how to install it on a VM machine  (http://www.sysads.co.uk/2014/06/install-league-legends-ubuntu-14-04/)

Comment: I'm having problems at the tuxlol part, how do i get mono 2.10.x?

Comment: Fixed it, to people like me (newbies to Ubuntu), install the mono-complete package, and then run this command : "mono tuxlol.exe patch --dir ~/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/LeagueOfLegends/dosdevices/c:/Riot\ Games/League\ of\ Legends/" the one at the guide doesn't work.

Comment: How did you get to the part where you can actually run games? I can run the game no probs, but when I start a game, it loads and when the bar hits 100% I can hear the ingame noise, but then instead of showing the game, it crashes. What am I missing? Or how do I found out what I'm missing?

Comment: Do you have a solution for game not loading after champion select?

Comment: As of September 2015, League of Legends is 100% working on Ubuntu 14.04 only by following steps 1, 2 and 3 of my answer. You just need to (1) install the proprietary video driver, (2) install playonlinux and (3) install League of Legends using playonlinux. That's it. Nothing else is required for a 100% working League of Legends. Enjoy your game on Linux!

Comment: For some reason the proprietary video driver does not work on my laptop, but I found that my CPU, an i7-4600M does support Shader 2.0 and actually runs the game very well. I'm running at around 100 FPS without the video card doing any work.

Comment: @renatov Do you know if these steps also work for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and/or Ubuntu 16.10?

Comment: 100+ fps no fight, in fight very choppy drops under < 30 fps. Fixed for me: Configure Wine, Staging tab, Enable CSMT. High to ultra in game. V-sync on stable 60 fps. i5-4690K, GTX 970 NVIDIA 367.57, 8GB, 16.04.1 LTS, PlayOnLinux 4.2.10, Wine 1.9.23-staging.

Comment: Need to add this: After about 30 minutes of play. Game becomes choppy. Low FPS. I turned GPU fan to high speed, at 30 degrees while playing (Strix cooling). Exiting game and reconnecting fixes it completely, and another 30 minutes of play is enjoyable, but not ideal. LOL ram usage goes from 800MB to 1.3GB and begins to lag. Really like Ubuntu. But as a gamer Windows is the more supported way :-/

Answer (score 3):

[image]

### Updated 2019

- Make sure your graphics drivers are up to date *and running*: [nVidia](https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) [AMD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1066105/how-to-install-amd-graphic-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04) (Intel is automatic) - use `nvidia-settings` to verify it's running at command line for nvidia
- Install [Lutris](https://lutris.net)
- Install [League](https://lutris.net/games/league-of-legends/)
- After every major League update, *UNINSTALL* completely & reinstall League again or it may break

[*Help Video*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0YW5ulQOaGk)

NOTE: League and graphics drivers run/load better with modern desktop environments such as [Budgie](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-budgie-desktop-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux) on the latest non-LTS Ubuntu

Now to get out of bronze....

Comment: I got out of bronze finally guys

Answer (score 0):

Figured I should post here my solution since it's basically the first thing that popped up on my google search when I ran into this problem, maybe save some other bloke the trouble of digging deeper.

***I.*** The accepted post does not fix the shop, because it does not install Internet Explorer, and the LOL client needs IE in order to generate the shop and whatnot, so basically what you need to do is:

1. Open PlayOnLinux
2. Select League of Legends
3. Go to Configure
4. Install Components
5. Install Internet Explorer 8 (make sure you are emulating Win XP for this to work)

***II.*** Making sure you are running Win XP:

1. Open PlayOnLinux
2. Select League of Legends
3. Go to Configure
4. Wine
5. Configure Wine
6. Applications
7. Windows Version [ Windows XP ]

Also if you go to Libraries here (after you have installed IE8) you should notice it will run the libraries needed for the shop to work.

Comment: Does work; make sure you install IE8 as described, and not with the standard applications installer (otherwise it ends up on its own virtual drive and is useless)

Comment: How do I even get to the store? My game seems to crash just before the game starts. I can see the loading bar/numbers, but when the game is about to start, I can heard the ingame noises, but instead of showing me the game, it crashes... Any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: I didn't have to install Internet Explorer and everything worked just fine. But I put an observation on my answer, saying that some people reported that IE is needed, so if they still have any issues after following those steps, they should install IE to see if it solves. See you in game!