# How do I execute a .exe file from a certain directory in another directory?

Tags: executable, execute-command

I'm trying execute tuxlol.exe.  I tried ./tuxlol but I keep getting error messages saying no such command exists.

The code I'm trying to execute in terminal is:

$ mono tuxlol.exe patch --dir "LEAGUE_OF_LEGENDS_DIR"

Here's the website where I'm getting information from.

[How to install League of Legends in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/459888/shop-and-in-game-item-shop-not-working-in-league-of-legend-lol/461256#461256)

Comment: what is the code inside it ? can you output ls -l ?

Comment: I don't understand what code you're referring to.  I'm trying to run this:  $ mono tuxlol.exe patch --dir "LEAGUE_OF_LEGENDS_DIR"

                                                       Obviously, replace LEAGUE_OF_LEGENDS_DIR with your League of Legends directory. In my case, it's installed here:

~/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/LeagueOfLegends/drive_c/Riot Games/League of Legends/
       Here's the full website where I am getting my information from.    http://askubuntu.com/questions/459888/shop-and-in-game-item-shop-not-working-in-league-of-legend-lol/461256#461256

Answer (score 0):

By downloading Wine, you will be able to run an Executable.  A *.*.exe (or in the old days .exec) is a Windows platform program that tell the code to initialize and run.
This is where Wine comes in.
http://Winehq.org
This is where any windows item you come across can be installed on to your system without Linux being confused.
LoL is current with version 1.79, which will play just about every game out there and execute about any file with the Windows platform code.