# TuxLoL patch on Play on Linux: invalid directory

Tags: 14.04, games, playonlinux, patch

I am following [this howto](https://askubuntu.com/questions/459888/shop-and-in-game-item-shop-not-working-in-league-of-legend-lol/461256#461256) described by [renatov](https://askubuntu.com/users/218356/renatov) to install LoL on ubuntu 14.04

I did as shown in the same tutorial i think..

so i get to the patching part:

```
mono tuxlol.exe patch --dir "~/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/LeagueOfLegends/dosdevices/c:/Riot Games/League of Legends"
mono tuxlol.exe patch --dir "~/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/LeagueOfLegends/drive_c/Riot Games/League of Legends"
```

I have tried both lines separately. What i get when i run either is:

```
The specified directory is invalid.
```

I've triple checked the path to both folders (where tuxlol was extracted to and where LoL is installed). What am I missing here??

Edit:
No idea why this worked now, since i had not before

ran the command like so:

```
mono tuxlol.exe patch --dir ~/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/LeagueOfLegends/dosdevices/c:/Riot\ Games/League\ of\ Legends/
```

and patch was succesful.
I was sure i had tried this already.. maybe I didn't, go figure.. going to continue his tutorial.

Edit (06/21):

Patch applied sucsessfuly.. however, i cannot fidn this folder:

```
/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/[virtualdrivename]/drive_c/Riot Games/League of Legends/RADS/solutions/lol_game_client_sln/releases/[0.0.0.XXX]/deploy/DATA/menu/hud
```

So cant apply corrections for store and shop. Any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I went to this page and follow all the instructions carefully.

Copy and paste the Directory route and it worked.

http://www.ugopiemontese.eu/2014/05/31/league-of-legends-ubuntu-14-04/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that there are spaces in the folder names. The command line interface reads this space as a new argument and not as part of the directory name, therefore you have to escape the spaces with a "\". This is why the final command works.