# Patching LoL with TuxLoL

Tags: 14.04, games, playonlinux, patch

I seem to have exactly the same issue as Guga had in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/483119/tuxlol-patch-on-play-on-linux-invalid-directory?newreg=0b4acf8b33944d7585ed7c7ff264ad16) question.

I was receiving the same message "invalid Directory." But in this case, I have removed all spaces from the path name. I have no problem changing my working directory to this but I cannot apply the actual path.

I successfully change directory with:

```
cd ~/Gamestuff/PlayOnLinux/LeagueOfLegends/drive_c/RiotGames/Leagueoflegends/
```

But when I try:

```
mono tuxlol.exe patch --dir ~/Gamestuff/PlayOnLinux/LeagueOfLegends/drive_c/RiotGames/Leagueoflegends/
```

I get

```
"The specified directory is invalid."
```

What could I be doing wrong? The answers to his question fixed the space issue, but I have none. I hate asking a separate question, but I've been stuck on this single issue for over an hour.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After `/drive_c` it should be `/Riot Games/League of Legends`. You need the spaces in that case since its the actual name of the folders.