# League of legends games will not start, bugsplat

Tags: ati, wine, games, playonlinux

I'm trying to run League of Legends on Ubuntu 14.04 using Play on Linux.

I followed [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/459888/shop-and-in-game-item-shop-not-working-in-league-of-legend-lol/461256#461256) to install it. I'm now using Amd's proprietary drivers (got an HD5770 graphics card if that matters). I installed the drivers using Ubuntu's `additional drivers` program.

It starts up fine, patches fine, logs in fine, I can create/join a game lobby etc. But when a game starts, no fullscreen window pops up, it's just a little wine icon on my dock, clicking it or switching windows doesn't work. After about a minute, I get a bugsplat error.

When running the game with the open-source amd drivers, the game *does* start up, but the performance is bad, that's why I'm trying to install the proprietary drivers.

Edit: if you're downvoting me, please tell me why. Are you missing information? Am I in the wrong place?

Comment: Has the game worked for you before? Are the people that wrote the guide using proprietary drivers like you?

Comment: The game used to work on my Ubuntu 12.04 installation. I did not use proprietary drivers, but the performance was terrible. I also just found out that open-source drivers work on 14.04 too, however as with 12.04, performance is horrendous. So the problem lies at the proprietary driver.

Comment: If you remember the wine version that was last working with it, try using that again.

Comment: @prusswan I think the problem lies with amd's proprietary driver, in this current installation LoL runs if I use the standard open-source drivers, but not when I switch to the proprietary amd one.

Comment: ok.. then you have answered your own question

Comment: All bug related issues should be asked on the lol Pol page [League Of Legends - Supported software - PlayOnLinux - Run your Windows applications on Linux easily!](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/app-1135-League_Of_Legends.html)

Comment: Also Give this a try: http://www.eurobytes.nl/tutorials/league-of-legends-under-ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

I`m using amd proprietary drivers, disabled the audio on game.cfg, i got just 17-18 fps, but the game is playable

Wine version 1.7.19LeagueOfLegends2

The shop doesnt work, so i need to change to another wine version with shop at