# Will a playonlinux installation affect my current (working) WoW with wine installation?

Tags: software-installation, games, lenovo, playonlinux

I "managed" to get World Of Warcraft working with no problems on my Lenovo Laptop. It got one of that awfull optimus graphic systems and it took some time. I want to install league of legends now and fear that an installation following this guide: [How to install League of Legends in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/459888/shop-and-in-game-item-shop-not-working-in-league-of-legend-lol/461256?newreg=07012e75bf29406185a06be042e55697)
will somehow affect my wow installion negativly.
Does anyone here has any experience on that topic?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It will not affect your WOW installation because Playonlinux creates it's own "virtual" disks (folders) into your home folder.

You can tell that it is indepedent although it's using wine.   :)

Comment: POL also allows you to manage multiple "disks" with a different version of wine for each (so you can, for example, test and see if the beta 1.7 wine will work better than the stable 1.6, without harming an existing working installation)