# League of Legends Update Failed

Tags: 14.04, wine, games, playonlinux

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS yesterday and today installed LoL with this guide: [How to install League of Legends in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/459888/shop-and-in-game-item-shop-not-working-in-league-of-legend-lol/461256#461256)

I did the TuxLoL patch without issue and opened LoL it started to patching. At 89% i got this error: [image: http://bit.ly/11sltq8]

How can i fix it? I'm new on Ubuntu trying to learn and wanna play LoL

Comment: Please avoid using link shorteners here. Especially when linking to questions, answers or comments from here.

Comment: I had same problem,  the problem was tor and privoxy which I had to stop both services, disable them and reboot the system, after reboot everything gone fine, can you confirm this for your situation?

Answer (score 0):

I had a lot of problem for for update my Lol on Ubuntu, the patcher was blocked when it was 270 Mb remaining. i tried a lot of solution and nothhing work. I fix this problem with a simple copy/paste from a Lol who worked. You should Uninstall the game, and Reinstall with Play on Linux. When POL ask you to launch the game, at this moment you just replace the folder Rads and here we go !
Enjoy