# League of Legends from windows on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

I'm quite new to Ubuntu and I would like to know if is possible to run windows version of League of legends on Ubuntu 14.04? My windows crashed and I installed Ubuntu and I would like to play it without installing and downloading it again. If so, could you describe me steps for linux dummies?

Comment: You may wish to start by checking the rating at https://appdb.winehq.org/

Comment: [This is the appdb link right to the ratings for the root Applicatoin](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=10436).  You have to verify which version you have.

Comment: "If so, could you describe me steps for linux dummies?" Nope, it will be difficult, not near newbie friendly and probably not running as well as you'd like. Alternative: install windows inside ubuntu with virtualbox and install LOL into that windows.

Comment: I was able to find this in a quick google search
http://askubuntu.com/questions/459888/shop-and-in-game-item-shop-not-working-in-league-of-legend-lol/461256#461256

Answer (score 1):

You will need to download League of Legends again, but, you will need a program named Wine, that makes almost any Windows program/game run on Ubuntu, or, like Rinzwid commented, install Virtual Box with Windows then install LOL on it. Hope that it solved your problem =) (sorry for bad English, I am Brazilian).