# How to install League of Legends on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

I'm pretty new to ubuntu and i have no idea on how to go through the process of installing the game. If anyone can help by posting a step by step process, it would be of great help 
Thank you

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/459888/shop-and-in-game-item-shop-not-working-in-league-of-legend-lol/461256#461256

Answer (score 3):

There is a very famous Linux and Mac program called **Wine**. You can use it to run Windows programs. There is no LoL Linux support, so you will have to do it through Wine.

Open a Terminal window (`Ctrl + Alt + T`) and type:

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```

Press ENTER. You will be prompted for your password. Type it and press ENTER.
Wine installation will begin. It will download about 350 MB of data and then install Wine.

After the installation ended, run `winecfg` in a terminal. Set default emulated Windows as Windows 7, apply and click OK.

Some errors may occur (we are playing with luck), but anyway, download League of Legends, install it (just double-click the installer or whatever and Wine will do it by itself) and run the game. This should work, but if it does not, I do not know what to do. It is a very long process, but you have to understand LoL is not a game made for Linux, and issues are common, normally with 3D Windows games.

If this does not work, do not worry: There are many games for Linux. You can install Steam (`sudo apt-get install steam` in a Terminal) and many games that run natively, like Wolfenstein, Urban Terror, Counter Strike, Team Fortress and so on.

**UPDATE1**: Hey, look: [WineHQ LoL link](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=19141)! This website shows how Windows programs run under Wine, and LoL has Gold rate. This means that people can play it and there is no issue! Good luck!

**UPDATE 2**: [This thread](http://forums.na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=2957372) is in the official LoL forums. It has a few more steps that may help you.

Comment: The easiest way is to use playonlinux, which has an automated wine instalation for league of legends.