# League of Legends crash while applying patches

Tags: playonlinux

I've installed Ubuntu few days ago and im just loving it! But the problem is that i only play one game, wich is league of legends and i can't run it :S

Ive tried install with PlayOnLinux and i can install it sucessfully but when the launcher opens and the game start to make the updating it always crash in step 2 "applying patches" and the % is always between 43 and 47%.

Ive look for a solution in the web but seems that no one have this specific problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install League of Legends in Ubuntu 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/459888/how-to-install-league-of-legends-in-ubuntu-14-04)

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently experiencing the identical problem.

The solution I've read is this:

- League of Legends requires AdobeAir to be installed. In PlayOnLinux, click on League of Legends -> Configure -> Install Components -> Adobe Air
- If Adobe Air cannot be installed, this may be due to the current Wine configuration. In PlayOnLinux, click on League of Legends -> Configure -> Wine -> COnfigure Wine -> Libraries -> *dnsapi -> Edit -> Click "Builtin". According to my research, this should allow for Adobe Air to be installed.

I'm currently working on applying this solution, and I'm not yet sure if it works for me.

Comment: Thanks mate, i was wondering if i am the only person experiencing that problem. Let me see if this works and i will give an answer soon.