# Problem installing League of legends on Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: wine, games, 16.10, playonlinux

I'm new to Ubuntu.

I'm trying to install "League of legends" and I think it all went OK.

I installed Wine and playonlinux, and the installation of league of legends was without problems. However, when I try to load it the following error message interrupts my launch:

[image: crash screenshot]

Can anyone help me to resolve this error and allow me to launch it, or reinstall it so that it works?

Comment: Install Dota 2 :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install League of Legends in Ubuntu 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/459888/how-to-install-league-of-legends-in-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: sorry but i didn't recive any help from that post i have always the same problem, that's could be maybe a problem with graphic drivers?

Comment: Most likely its because the new alpha client just progressed into beta and is now the default. There are some missing libraries apparently recommend checking out this reddit sub - https://www.reddit.com/r/leagueoflinux/