# Error while trying to install LoL through Playonlinux

Tags: 16.04, games, playonlinux

I'm trying to install League of Legends through Playonlinux on Ubuntu 16.04. I'm starting with wine & playonlinux totally uninstalled, and following these directions: [How to install League of Legends in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/459888/how-to-install-league-of-legends-in-ubuntu?newreg=8151a64c21ec494fb0cf94195a24acf8)

When I try and launch the game through playonlinux, it gets most of the way through the installation and then crashes and gives a popup: "The program LolPatcher.exe has encountered a serious problem and needs to close. We are sorry for the inconvenience."

Here's the playonlinux output in the terminal just prior to and then at the crash:

`[POL_System_CheckFS] Message: Checking filesystem for lol.launcher.admin.exe
[POL_Wine] Message: Running wine-1.9.2-LeagueOfLegends5 lol.launcher.admin.exe (Working directory : ~/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/LeagueOfLegends/drive_c/Riot Games/League of Legends)
[POL_Wine] Message: Notice: PlayOnLinux deliberately disables winemenubuilder. See http://www.playonlinux.com/fr/page-26-Winemenubuilder.html
[POL_Wine] Message: Wine return: 0
wine: Unhandled exception 0x40000015 in thread 52 at address 0x74121d (thread 0052), starting debugger...`

I've googled the error 

`[POL_Wine] Message: Wine return: 0
wine: Unhandled exception 0x40000015 in thread 52 at address 0x74121d (thread 0052), starting debugger...`

but pretty much every solution is "reinstall playonlinux" and I've tried that 3 times now with no success.

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up going with Lutris. It works well right off the bat - I never managed to get anything else to work.
https://lutris.net/

Answer (score 1):

I use q4wine and winetrix.

create a 32 bit XP prefix.

install: adobeair, directx9 and vcruntime 2015.

set dll override:msvcp140 and vcruntime140.

install LOL, or copy the riot games folder from another installation

make your launcher with q4wine

Note:client renderer randomly hangs. just end process and relaunch

PS: I'm using wine 2.01

Comment: sorry I don't fully understand all of that.

to confirm:
does 'create a 32 bit XP prefix' mean this: 
```WINEPREFIX="$HOME/prefix32" WINEARCH=win32 wine wineboot```
?

is copying the riot games folder from a windows system as easy as just putting it on a usb and then copying it from the usb onto the cdrive folder on ubuntu? or does it need to have windows line endings and stuff changed?

and how does one 'set dll override:msvcp140 and vcruntime140' ?

(also thanks for the hasty response)

Comment: yes that is the command line. but is easier to use the GUI `q4wine`. you can do everything with it. yes just copy from a windows install and put in C: of the prefix. `winecfg', Libraries tab is where you set the overrides.

Comment: so I installed adobeair, directx9, and vcrun2013. it warned me that I shouldn't be using directx9 because it's out of date, but it still went through so I just left it.. there was no vcrun2015 though and I'm wondering if that's why I now can't find msvcp140 and vcruntime140 in the winecfg libraries that can be overridden. There are lots of similar options but none matching those.

Comment: yes. download windows installer and run it in the prefix. the warning about DX9is because most programs don't need the entire setup.

Comment: not windows,  VC Runtime 2015  right???  yes run it in wine under the prefix for LOL. are you using q4wine? or manualLy with playinlinux?

Comment: I'm using q4wine. I can't find a version of the windows installer exe that will run properly. they all either say 'wrong platform' or 'path not found'. VC runtime 2015 is not an option in q4wine, vcrun13 is the closest I see.

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145 get the x86 version